# I have one csv file with acronyms, and another file with the translations to those acronyms, how to generate a new .csv file with the translated info?

Tags: arrays, csv

I would really appreciate any help you could provide me solving this problem.

I have two input .csv files in python. One of them, is a file that has different machine codes (one per line):

```
epdmolpd37901v,
epzsttom35101v,
epdsrptb36301v,
ppdpedbm07903,
ppdtrnod07202a,
```

These codes have a way to be translated:

The first letter is the environment of the machines:

```
P - Production
E - External User Acceptance
```

The following 2 letters are the location:

```
PD - Primary Data Center
PZ - Primary DMZ
```

The following 5 letters are the description, and that successively...

In another .csv file i have bi-dimensional arrays that have the translations to these acronyms:

```
P,Production
E,External User Acceptance

PD, Primary Data Center
PZ, Primary DMZ
```

etc...

How do I generate a different .csv file that will write the following information?

```
epdmolpd37901v, External User Acceptance, Primary Data Center, etc...
epzsttom35101v, External User Acceptance, Primary DMZ, etc...
etc...
```

The code has to read the first character from one .csv file, then go to the other .csv file a search on the first column for the same character and the respective translation, and finally write the translation of the full code in a new csv_file.

Can anyone help me with this? I am a beginner and would really appreciate any guidance.

My code right now (needs some work):
[image]

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify language of your choice, so I would analyze this as pseudocode. I assume here that acronyms are UNIQUE so you can't have "P" as first position and "P" at a different one.

```
Read original file into a list  "of"
Read translation file into a list "tf"

; do translation file first
for each line in translation file {
    split the line at "," and put each part in an array or hash list
    ; allows you to look up a value
}

; create a function that has input "acronym" and output "translation"
 function translateit(acr as string) : as string
   {  look it up in structure  and return string  }


; create the output file "outfile"
outfile = create_a_file()

; do the original file
for each line in original file {
    writetooutput (original line)
    writetooutput(   translateit (left 1 )  )  ; char 1
    writetooutput(   translateit (mid 2,2)  )  ; char 2,3
    ; ...      
}
```

This way you "translate" the original line, piece by piece, as desired.